# Google Play 11157 unsupported devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I made game in Unity3D, then upload it to the Google Play store. Developer console says there is 11157 unsupported devices (only 1020 supported). I think I can't find my app through my phone because it's on unsupported list.

What Can I do to make it supported by more devices?

---

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <!-- This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.

  --> 
- <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.google.unity" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> 
- <!--  Google Mobile Ads Permissions 
  --> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
- <!--  Uncomment to add billing for in-app purchase ads 
  --> 
- <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/> 
  --> 
- <application>
- <!--  Denote the referenced Google Play services version 
  --> 
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
- <!--  Google Mobile Ads Activity 
  --> 
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" /> 
- <!--  InAppPurchase Activity 
  --> 
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" /> 
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set minimum API level to something lower. API 19 4.4 Kitkat will cover around 74%. API 16 4.1 Jelly Bean will cover around 95%. Based on [Platform statistics](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform)

Check if your Android manifest doesn't require a lot of features. You can add `android:required="false"` to them.

Don't leave Texture Compression set to Tegra.

Comment: It was Tegra blame. Thanks